# How to play multiple videos in Youtubeplayer - API?

Tags: android, string, android-studio, youtube, android-youtube-api

I am trying to play a number of videos from YouTube using the YouTube Player API in Android Studio. I have the Video Id of each videos. Now I want the player to play video when each button is clicked.

```
        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {

            youTubePlayer.loadVideo("video_id");

        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
      }
```

when i used this method, I don't know how to 'change the video id' when second button is clicked to play the second video in the same player.

**Any answers are highly appreciated!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
         YouTubePlayer  player;//Inilize this in before oncreate method

        videos_listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
               String selectedurl=videoslist.get(position);  //videolist is the list of all video view ids             
               player.pause();
               player.cueVideo(selectedurl);
               }

            @Override
             public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored)
               {
                 this.player=player;
                 if (!wasRestored) {
                  player.cueVideo(videoslist.get(0)); // Plays https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=videoid
               }
```

Comment: thnkx siddarth for your help

Comment: i want to play video in activity in Youtubeplayerview

Comment: youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
        youTubeView.initialize(getString(R.string.youtubeAPiKey), this);  i added this 2 lines oncreate but onchanging a video i used player methods only